# actix_web middleware ErrorHandlers return error message in ServiceResponse

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am trying to capture errors that may occur for requests made to my server.

This came up when I was receiving a 400 on one of my POST requests (which was thrown before even getting to my request handler method) and I was receiving no feedback as to what the issue was after enabling the debug logs I saw the issue

```
[actix_web::types::json] Failed to deserialize Json from payload. Request path: /new_endpoint
Json deserialize error: invalid length: expected one of [36, 32], found 10 at line 2 column 20
[DEBUG actix_web::middleware::logger] Error in response: Deserialize(Error("invalid length: expected one of [36, 32], found 10", line: 2, column: 20))
```

Now, I want to be able to capture that error so that it can be sent back in the body of the 400 response.

I've started with

```
App::new()
    .wrap(ErrorHandlers::new().handler(http::StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST, handle_bad_request))
```

and in `handle_bad_request` I am able to modify the response body to contain new information

```
fn handle_bad_request<B>(mut res: dev::ServiceResponse<B>) -> Result<ErrorHandlerResponse<Body>> {
    res.response_mut().headers_mut().insert(
        http::header::CONTENT_TYPE,
        http::HeaderValue::from_static("application/json"),
    );
    let new_res: ServiceResponse<Body> = res.map_body(|_head, _body| {
        ResponseBody::Other(Body::Message(Box::new("New Response Body")))
    });
    Ok(ErrorHandlerResponse::Response(new_res))
}
```

Ideally what I want to do is take the error in `ServiceResponse` and send it back in the response. I am able to read the error by doing

```
match res.response().error() {
    Some(e) =>  println!("{0}", e),
    None =>  println!("Error None")
};
```

but as for actually taking that error and sending it back in the response I am not able to figure that out.

Comment: Can't you just put `format!("{:?}", res.reponse().error())` in your response body?

Comment: Just got the chance to try this and it appears to be working! I can't believe I never thought to try that. I will update with an answer here shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this `format!("{:?}", res.reponse().error())` was needed. That does return `Some(error message)` so just to account for that the following worked.

```
let errorMsg: String = match res.response().error() {
    Some(e) => format!("{:?}", e),
    None =>  String::from("Unknown Error")
};
let new_res: ServiceResponse<Body> = res.map_body(|_head, _body| {
    ResponseBody::Other(Body::Message(Box::new(errorMsg)))
});
Ok(ErrorHandlerResponse::Response(new_res))
```

Comment: This does not seam to work in the recent Actix. Do you know how to achieve it in current version?